# NSDictionary to NSArray

Tags: dictionary, nsarray, nsdictionary

I hope to map the NSDictionary structure below:

```
(
        {
        key = 1;
        store = News;
        value =         {
            Title = "A";
        };
    },
        {
        key = 2;
        store = News;
        value =         {
            Title = "B";
        };
    }
)
```

to NSArray.

Unfortunately I can't find any suitable method in NSDictionary.

Welcome any comment

Comment: explicit cast (NSArray*)dict does what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys])
{
    id value = [d1 valueForKey:key];
    [mutableArray addObject:value];
}
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
```

Convert the NSDictionary to NSArray.

Comment: explicit cast (NSArray*)dict does what I want